# How to use MapReduce for k-Means Spatial Clustering

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, cluster-analysis, spatial

I'm new to mongodb and map-reduce and want to evaluate spatial data by using a k-means spatial clustering. I found this [article](http://blog.data-miners.com/2008/02/mapreduce-and-k-means-clustering.html) which seems to be a good description of the algorithm, but I have no clue how to translate this into a mongo shell script. Assume my data looks like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID(),
  loc: {x: <longitude>, y: <latitude>},
  user: <userid>
}
```

And I can use { k = sqrt(n/2) } where n is the number of samples.
I can use aggregates to get the bounding extents of the data and the count, etc.
I kind of got lost with the reference to a file of the cluster points, which I assume would be just another collection and I have no idea how to do the iteration or if that would be done in the client or the database?

Ok, I have made a little progress on this in that I have generated and array of initial random points that I need to compute the sum of least squares against during the map-reduce phase, but I do not know how to pass these to the map function. I took a stab at writing the map function:

```
var mapCluster = function() {
    var key = -1;
    var sos = 0;
    var pos;
    for (var i=0; i<pts.length; i++) {
        var dx = pts[i][0] - this.arguments.pos[0];
        var dy = pts[i][1] - this.arguments.pos[1];
        var sumOfSquare = dx*dx + dy*dy;
        if (i == 0 || sumOfSquares < sos) {
            key = i;
            sos = sumOfSquares;
            pos = this.arguments.pos;
        }
    }
    emit(key, pos);
};
```

I this case the cluster points are like, which is probably will not work:

```
var pts = [ [x,y], [x1,y1], ... ];
```

So for each mr iteration, we compare all the collection points against this array and emit the index of the point that we are closest to along with location of the collection point then in the reduce function the average of the points associated with each index would be used to create the new cluster point location. Then in the finialize function I can update the cluster document.

I assume I could do a findOne() on the cluster document to load the cluster points in the map function but do we want to load this document on every call to map? or is there a way to load it once for each iteraction?

So it looks like you can do the above using the scope variable like this:

```
db.main.mapReduce( mapCluster, mapReduce, { scope: { pnts: pnts, ... }} );
```

You have to be careful about variable names in the scope as these are placed in the scope of the map, reduce and finialize functions they can collide with existing variable names.

Comment: yes, but I haven't looked at it in 3 yrs and can't remember what I did. I believe I ended up using http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/classification/node13.html the iterative self organizing cluster described there.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Note that you will need more than one round of mappers.

With the canonical approach of running k-means on MR, you need one mapper/reducer *per iteration*.

So, can you try to write the map and reduce steps of a single iteration only?

Comment: To be honest, I have never written a map-reduce function yet, this is my first attempt, which may be to complicated but it is what I need to achieve. My first step is to get an aggregate to extract the spatial extents and I just got an issue with that resolved so I can move forward with that. Next I will generate k random points needed for the initial condition.

Comment: After than I'm not sure how to do the map-reduce using those random points and my table of points needed for one iteration. I assume that I need some function that I can run that will do the iteration and determine when to stop, but I'm not sure where or how that should be structured. Pointers to other code that do something similar would be helpful or an example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Try a single iteration first, assign each object to the least-sum-of-squares random cluster center. Then in the reducer, recompute the cluster centers. For extra performance, use a combiner to avoid producing interim data of size "n".

Comment: Thanks this was good advice. I have read a little more and updated the question with my progress.